# can we use php echo function in html mail $messahe .='<h3>phone:<?php echo $phone;?></h3>'

Tags: php

```
   <?php 
    $to = 'maryjane@email.com';
    $subject = 'Marriage Proposal'; 
    $from = 'peterparker@email.com';   // To send HTML mail, the  Content-type header must be set 
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";    
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";   // Create email headers 
    $headers .= 'From: '.$user_email."\r\n".     'Reply-To: '.$user_email."\r\n" .     'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();   // Compose a simple HTML email message 
    $message = '<html><body>'; $message .= '<h3 style="color:#f40;">Email:<?php echo $from;?></h3>'; $message .= '<h3>Phone:<?php $phone;></h3>'; $message .= '</body></html>';   // Sending email 
    if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
    {     
       echo 'Your mail has been sent successfully.'; 
    } else{     
         echo 'Unable to send email. Please try again.';
    } 
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$message = '<html><body>'; 
$message .= '<h3 style="color:#f40;">Email:'.$from.'</h3>'; 
$message .= '<h3>Phone:'.$phone.'</h3>'; 
$message .= '</body></html>';   // Sending email
```

Answer (score -1):

If Its a PHP script, then you can use any PHP function including echo.
Clean way to do this -

```
echo '<h3>'.$phone.'</h3>';
```

Comment: I have modified it to remove double quotes.